# Directline activities in custom domain - 502 Bad gateway - node js/java script - azure chatbot

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-web-app-service, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I have deployed the azure app service in my custom domain say test.com due to internal company restrictions. So when i try to access the chatbot after deployment through directline i see 502 bad gateway error

**customChatbot.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
      <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
      <script>
      
            const styleOptions = {
            bubbleBackground: '#E5E8E8',
            bubbleFromUserBackground: '#D9EDF9',
            hideUploadButton: true,
            sendBoxTextWrap: true
        };

        const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function (_ref) {
            var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
            return function (next) {
                return function (action) {
                    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                            console.log("inside conversation history");
                            dispatch({
                                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                                payload: {
                                    name: 'conversationHistory',
                                    value: { id: 'me', name: 'XXX@test.com' },

                                }
                            });
                            }
                    return next(action);
                }

            }


        });

         window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
               directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                  token: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
               }),
               userID: 'shivakumar.kandasamy@test.com',
               bot: { id: 'hpusstoredevbot' },
               username: 'Sivakumar Kandasamy',
               locale: 'en-US',
               botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
               userAvatarInitials: 'WW',
               store: store,
               styleOptions: styleOptions
            },
            document.getElementById('webchat')
         );
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**RESPONSE**
{
"error": {
"code": "BotError",
"message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
}
}

**Request Header**

[image]

I have Azure AD enabled for this application but im not sure how to integrate it with direct line or how it works with direct line. I understand that directline needs a secret/token but in order to enter a custom domain it might need some authentication but how to achieve this with directline? is this an issue with authentication? Can someone give me pointers on this. Im using node js.

Exception that i see in application insights

**Message   POST to devbot failed: An error occurred while sending the request. An error occurred while sending the request. The remote name could not be resolved: 'devbot.corp.xxcloud.net'**
Exception type :    System.Net.WebException
Failed method  :    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream
Custom Properties
Conversation ID XXXXXXX-c
Correlation ID  |XXXXXXX
Activity Type   conversationUpdate
Bot Endpoint    https://devbot.corp.xxcloud.net/api/messages
Recipient ID    devbot@NWGv3oCIAyXMXX
Activity ID JiR6p5WTnLOXXX
Channel ID  directline
From ID XXXXXXX-c
Bot ID  devbot
Background  |XXXXXXX

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotException:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__36.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 480)
Inner exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__36.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__36.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 452)
Inner exception System.Net.WebException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback (System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the `activities` ? Such as` request params` ,`beartoken`, and `header` and so on. Pls hide confidential information.

Comment: @JasonPan updated the request data in the post.

Comment: @JasonPan i tried the same via postman by initializin the conversation https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations and then passing the toke on to https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{{CONVID}}/activities with a sample message in body `{"type": "message","from": {"id": "user1" }, "text":  "hello"}` . i could replicate 502 bad gateway there too

Comment: `/api/messages/v3/directline/conversations`.

Comment: Add postfix to the bot URL,then try.

Comment: I will try to solve it, pls  wait.

Comment: it says 500 internal server error when i try doing a post with https://directline.botframework.com/api/messages/v3/directline/conversations. My custom messages end point is something like https://devbot.corp.net/api/messages

Comment: It works for me. Pls read it. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/issues/106

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219531/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-shiva).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was our **node js SDK**. Our SDK was V3. According to microsoft team, **you can access a bot inside ILB ASE internally only when your node js SDK is of version V4 or higher** (using direct line app service extension). This is strange but it happens only with node js but not with .NET . .NET sdk can still access the service withing ILB ASE internally for sdk V3.They are yet to publish this on their documentation. Since the issue is only with accessing it internally within our premises So we are accessing the bot using application gateway with public dns

Answer (score 1):

Follow the offical document, you can fixed the issue.

Pay attention to the format of `Authorization`.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update Jason.This works fine if the endpoint is https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/messages . But doesnt seem to be working for 
https://XXX.corp.cloud.net/api/messages